# Retrieve updated view height

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, layout

In my android application, I have a linear layout made of two edittext field whose contents are changed programmatically. I also adjust the number of lines of the second based on what fits in the activity. However when the text in the chapter layout (on top) is set to more than 1 line (and so different from the one in xml), the other edittext is like if it didn't notice the different height (which goes from end of first edit box to bottom of the activity). Here is the relevant part of the code:

```
        tvTitleChapter.setText(...more than one line...));
        tvBookChapter.setText(... a lot of text...);

        int height = tvBookChapter.getHeight();
        Layout layout = tvBookChapter.getLayout();

        int lastVisibleLineNumber = layout.getLineForVertical(height);
        while (tvBookChapter.getHeight() < layout.getLineBottom(lastVisibleLineNumber)) {
            lastVisibleLineNumber--;   // from logs this loop is called only once 
        }
        int tempend = layout.getLineEnd(lastVisibleLineNumber);
        curtext = curtext.substring(0, tempend);
        tvBookChapter.setText(curtext);
```

However the second edit text shows a couple extra lines (if scrolled).

Any idea on what causes the problem and how it could be solved?

Thank you very much